# How to add external javascript file into all html files in directory?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any simple way to add or link external javascript file into all `.html` files in directory by java script.

I have a folder called `src` in that there are n-number of `.html` files are available. I need to provide `<script src="event_listener.js"></script>` manually in  each `.html` files, I'm looking for automate this step by javascript. So far I tried by reading a file like below,

```
$.get(path_of_the_file, function( my_var ) {
    console.log(my_var)
}, 'html');
```

But I'm having `cross-domain` issue. So i'm unable to achieve the same.

I'm new to javascript. So I don't have an idea to solve this issue.
If I have this problem in python I could try something like below,

```
import os
file_path=os.listdir('path_of_the_files')
for file_ in file_path:
   if file_.endswith('.html'):
      fo=open(file_path+'/'+file_,'r')
      i=0
      lines=fo.readlines()
      for line in lines:
         if line.strip().startwith("</html>"):
              el=i
              break
         i+=1
      lines.insert(["<script src="event_listener.js"></script>"],i)
      fo.close()
      fo=open(file_path+'/'+file_,'w')
      fo.writelines( lines )
```

At the worst case I could try with python.

But I hope this could be solved by without moving to python.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i think you have to do it manually

Comment: @AdeshKumar - Thanks for the comment. But I have nearly 20 to 50 html files and it's dynamic. So it's a critical part to do it by manually.

Comment: With only HTML, you need to reference your JavaScript file. There is no workaround.

Comment: As I know you have to do it maually. or you can go to any other language for doing so as javascript doesn't provide it.

Comment: @rojadesign - I can use javascript also :). Is there any way I can achieve this by javascript

Comment: Having a main index file and loading these HTML files into it is definitely the best route here; you should focus on fixing the CORS issue. Why are they hosted on a different server? Can you configure it to allow CORS requests? Still, all of this sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @MohamedThasinah What is the point of that? Obviously, you would still use JS. I would add the `<script>` to each HTML file manually. It's copy and paste.

Comment: If you are only proficient on javascript, you can do it using node.js. There might be a hacky way to preprocess all html files dynamically(and cache them), parse the html and then inject the <script> tag into desired position and return them to client. But imho it's not the right way to do it. The right way would be actually including all script tags in headers manually, or merging parts of HTML that has the common includes using some kind of server side script (PHP, Node.js etc.)

Comment: @basar - I got your point. i'll try to do this

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Please be aware that if you add such script tags by any way which seems like a bot then your application might get banned because of XSS issue, I agree with basar to proceed further.

Comment: @KunalNavhate - Thanks for your valuable comment. I was unaware of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nodeJS filesystem API to edit all files in the folder.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Here's how you read all files in a folder and apply a `onFileContent` function to each file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readFiles(dirname, onFileContent, onError) {
  fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, filenames) {
    if (err) {
      onError(err);
      return;
    }
    filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
      fs.readFile(dirname + filename, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
        if (err) {
          onError(err);
          return;
        }
        onFileContent(filename, content);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And this is how you write to a single file:

```
fs.writeFile('filename.txt', newValue, 'utf-8', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Hope this helps you. Don't forget that this is Nodejs, it's not a browser script.